# CSS Change color of border twice while giving it a left to right effect

Tags: html, css

I want to combine two animations in order to achieve a bottom border that turns to white and fills from left to right and then goes back to the initial color giving the effect that the white line dissapears.

I found this pen that shows how I want the white line to show up (it's the third button, curmudgeon). It should dissapear from left to right too.
https://codepen.io/lesbaa/pen/dojGVL

I created the border changing colors in steps in the code below.

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}

.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #161a1c;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #1f262d;
}

.box:hover {
  animation: line 1s;
}

@keyframes line {
  50% {
    border-bottom: 3px white solid;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Any ideas how I could achieve this?
Assuming it's even possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using a `:pseudo-element` and `transition`.

```css
body {
  background: #444;
}
.box {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #161a1c;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #1f262d;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 145%;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -145%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #1f262d 0%, white 45%, white 100%);
  z-index: 1;
  transition: left 0s;
}
.box:hover::after {
  left: 145%;
  transition: left 1s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `linear-gradient` and adjust `background-size`/`background-position` on hover:

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}

.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image:linear-gradient(#fff,#fff);
  background-position:bottom left;
  background-size:0% 2px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-color:#161a1c;
  transition:
   background-size 1s, /*animate the background-size*/
   background-position 0s 1s; /*don't animate position and add a delay */
}

.box:hover {
  background-position:bottom right;
  background-size:100% 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

**UPDATE**

You can also do it like this:

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}

.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image:linear-gradient(#fff,#fff);
  background-position:200% 100%;
  background-size:200% 2px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-color:#161a1c;
  transition:0s;
}

.box:hover {
  background-position:-100% 100%;
  transition:all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking to achieve, I wanted the line disappearing still on hover and not after moving out the mouse. However, it's still an interesting option and might be helpfull for others.
Thanks for your colaboration.

Comment: @Alex I have added another example if you want ;)

Comment: Yes, that one would achieve the effect I wanted. Thanks again.